# Why is this rails simple form not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, simple-form, rails-routing

I am making a rails application.  After a user has registered (I have already created user registration with devise), they can fill out this form that will contain their profile information.  I have done this several times, and i can't find what is wrong.  Here is the model:

```
class Information < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is the  controller:

```
class InformationsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @information = Information.new
    end
    def create
        @information = Information.create(params[:information])
        redirect_to student_path
    end
    def index
    end
end
```

And here is the view for the new action.

```
<div class="span6 offset3 text-center">
<h1>Edit your information</h1>

    <%= simple_form_for @information do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :skills %>
        <%= f.input :looking_for, :label => 'What help do you need?' %>
        <%= f.input :my_idea %>
        <%= submit_tag "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is the line in the routes file:

```
resources :informations
```

I get the following errors which make no sense to me:

undefined method `information_index_path' for #<#:0x007f9c00c7b3e0>

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks.

UPDATE:

When I did rake routes, For informations#create, which is what the form should be going to, it has a blank path. There is also informations#index, which is what I guess its going to now. How do I get it to go to informations#create if the path is blank?

Comment: Something is up with the syntax of your ERB. Try getting rid of the comments for now. Also, are you using an IDE to alert you to malformed ERB?

Comment: I am not using an IDE.  I am using sublime.  I got rid of the comments and edited the question with the new error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with naming the resource information.  As information is the same plural as it is singular, it was confusing rails.  I renamed the model description and the controller descriptions_controller, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please try yanking out the comments (# signs) in lines 6 and 9 of your view.  They might be messing up the ERB processing.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and now i get the error: undefined method `information_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f9c036ebfa8>:0x007f9c00c7b3e0>

Comment: Time for some `rake routes` action.

Comment: Interesting.  When I did rake routes, For informations#create, which is what the form should be going to, it has a blank path.  There is also informations#index, which is what I guess its going to now.  How do I get it to go to informations#create if the path is blank?

Comment: Please edit your question with `routes.rb`, or accept @Dave's response and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `informations_path`? See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: I looked at that for a while actually.  Which part in particular are you referring to?  and do you mean do 'simple_form_for informations_path'?

Comment: Yeah I figured. Just making sure you saw that reference--Section 2.3 in particular. I didn't see how you use the path, but where you use `information_index_path`, try replacing with `informations_path`.

Comment: I don't ever use information_index_path though.  Its automatically taking me there.  I want to go to informations#create but for some reason the routes.rb file did not create that route.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying there isn't a path called `new_information_path`? Maybe you want `simple_form_for new_information_path`. I haven't used `simple_form_for`.

Comment: I ran rake routes.  There is no path for informations#create and i can't figure out why because in the routes.rb file I say resources :informations which should automatically create it like it did the other informations routes.

Comment: Yes, that is strange. Make sure there is nothing in your `routes.rb` corresponding to the stuff in Section 4.6.

Comment: Strange.  Yea, there's nothing like that in my routes.rb file

Comment: Just for fun, try `simple_form_for new_information_path`. If that doesn't work, I got nothing.